# HttpError 400 when trying to run DataProcSparkOperator task from a local Airflow

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm testing out a DAG that I used to have running on Google Composer without error, on a local install of Airflow. The DAG spins up a Google Dataproc cluster, runs a Spark job (JAR file located on a GS bucket), then spins down the cluster.

The DataProcSparkOperator task fails immediately each time with the following error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://dataproc.googleapis.com/v1beta2/projects//regions/global/jobs:submit?alt=json returned "Invalid resource field value in the request.">
```

It looks as though the URI is incorrect/incomplete, but I am not sure what is causing it. Below is the meat of my DAG. All the other tasks execute without error, and the only difference is the DAG is no longer running on Composer:

```
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email': models.Variable.get('email'),
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': dt.timedelta(seconds=30),
    'project_id': models.Variable.get('gcp_project'),
    'cluster_name': 'susi-bsm-cluster-{{ ds_nodash }}'
}

def slack():
    '''Posts to Slack if the Spark job fails'''
    text = ':x: The DAG *{}* broke and I am not smart enough to fix it. Check the StackDriver and DataProc logs.'.format(DAG_NAME)
    s.post_slack(SLACK_URI, text)

with DAG(DAG_NAME, schedule_interval='@once',
    default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:
    # pylint: disable=no-value-for-parameter

    delete_existing_parquet = bo.BashOperator(
        task_id = 'delete_existing_parquet',
        bash_command = 'gsutil rm -r {}/susi/bsm/bsm.parquet'.format(GCS_BUCKET)
    )

    create_dataproc_cluster = dpo.DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
        task_id = 'create_dataproc_cluster',
        num_workers = num_workers_override or models.Variable.get('default_dataproc_workers'),
        zone = models.Variable.get('gce_zone'),
        init_actions_uris = ['gs://cjones-composer-test/susi/susi-bsm-dataproc-init.sh'],
        trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    run_spark_job = dpo.DataProcSparkOperator(
       task_id = 'run_spark_job',
       main_class = MAIN_CLASS,
       dataproc_spark_jars = [MAIN_JAR],
       arguments=['{}/susi.conf'.format(CONF_DEST), DATE_CONST]
    )

    notify_on_fail = po.PythonOperator(
        task_id = 'output_to_slack',
        python_callable = slack,
        trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ONE_FAILED
    )

    delete_dataproc_cluster = dpo.DataprocClusterDeleteOperator(
       task_id = 'delete_dataproc_cluster',
       trigger_rule = trigger_rule.TriggerRule.ALL_DONE
    )

    delete_existing_parquet >> create_dataproc_cluster >> run_spark_job >> delete_dataproc_cluster >> notify_on_fail
```

Any assistance with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looking at the URI the project-id is missing.
I am guessing you set the `gcp_project` variable in your composer environment?
what about your environment when you ran it locally?

Comment: @cyxxy thanks for your response - I have set the gcp_project variable in my local Airflow install - I know it works because the spinup and teardown dataproc tasks work fine

Comment: Oh, it looks like that unlike the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`, the `DataProcSparkOperator` does not take `project_id` as a parameter. It gets the project_id from the Airflow connection. You either explicitly set the `gcp_conn_id` parameter, or configure the default `google_cloud_default` connection.
See [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f8dacae03340cb8423e37d7b053e7625a157f89e/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L1058)

Comment: [continued] relevant code:[here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f8dacae03340cb8423e37d7b053e7625a157f89e/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L1081) and [here](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/f8dacae03340cb8423e37d7b053e7625a157f89e/airflow/contrib/operators/dataproc_operator.py#L1096)
And on Composer the default `google_cloud_default` connection is [configured for you](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections) so that explains why you only observe this locally.
Can you check and report back if this is the root cause?

Comment: @cyxxy that worked perfectly, thanks! Did you want to write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Cool glad it is solved. I will write up an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`, the `DataProcSparkOperator` does not take the `project_id` as a parameter. It gets it from the Airflow connection (if you do not specify the `gcp_conn_id` parameter, it defaults to `google_cloud_default`). You have to configure your connection.

The reason you don't see this while running DAG in Composer is that Composer [configures](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/connections) the `google_cloud_default` connection.